# Is it correct to use "we too gone through..."?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

Is this a correct sentence:

> We too gone through such a situation.

I felt that a better alternative is:

> We had also gone through such a situation.

Which is the correct usage?

Comment: Will be better on ELL than on ELU. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your examples the word 'gone' should be replaced by 'been':

> We too have been through such a situation.

Or:

> We have also been through such a situation.

I think the second one feels more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct, but it the problem is not the switch to “too” but the lack of the auxiliary “had”

> We too had gone through such a situation.

Would be perfectly grammatical, though a bit awkward.

Comment: If `had` was there in the sentence, then it does sound natural. :)